# How to connect to external FTP from NiFi running in docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ftp, apache-nifi

I have:

1. NiFi running in docker container. I'm running NiFi via Docker Compose with the following config:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:latest
    container_name: nifi
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"
    volumes:
      - ./database_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/database_repository
      - ./flowfile_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository
      - ./content_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
      - ./provenance_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/provenance_repository
      - ./state:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/state
      - ./logs:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
      - ./conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
    restart: always
```

2. FTP server located on localhost (outside the container)
3. In the NiFi route i'm using a GetFTP processor which tries unsuccessfully to connect to localhost:21
   [image]

I understand that the problem is that localhost is not available, because container is isolated. What and how to configure in the docker-compose.yml configuration to solve the problem?

Comment: This does not look like a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: localhost for docker is docker itself. You have to specify exact ip or hostname where ftp is running instead of localhost.